# Iterate over array of args in scipy.integrate without for-loops

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say I have a function f(x) = a*x which I'd like to integrate over x for a given a. I want to be able to pass scipy.integrate.quad an array of arg 'a' to iterate over. For just one parameter I know this can be done via

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
param = 1 
def f(x,a):
    return a*x
integral = integrate.quad(f,0,1,args = (param)) # 0,1 are just arbitrary limits of integration
print(integral)
```

which works as expected. However, if I want to iterate over an array of param values, ex.)

```
param = np.array([1,2])
def f(x,a):
    return a*x
integral = integrate.quad(f,0,1,args = (param))
print(integral)
```

I get the error: "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". Obviously I can avoid this by implementing something like

```
integrals = []
for i in param:
    integrals.append(integrate.quad(f,0,1,args = (i)))
```

but I'd like to avoid for-loops where possible in the interest of keeping the code fast for larger sized param arrays and multiple integrals. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Don't use `quad`.  It isn't set up to work with multiple cases.

Comment: Ah, do you recommend an integrator that's more compatible with my situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try quad_vec: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html

Also don't forget a comma for an argument tuple: `args=(i, )`

Comment: Based on the documentation, I don't think that function takes args as an argument. This does work, though, if I use a lambda function instead of def. I'll have to think if I can get away with not defining function or not.